# datagridview позиция слов

Tags: c#, строки, datagridview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести каждую позицию слова в отдельному столбце грида?
Вывожу позиции так:

```
 string value = dataGridView8.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        string str = richTextBox2.Text;
        int length = str.Length;
 while (true)
        {
            int i = str.IndexOf(value);
            if (i == -1) break;

            dataGridView9.Rows.Add(i.ToString());
            str = str.Substring(i + value.Length);
        }
```

Результат следующий: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно,например, чтобы "9" было в "N1", а "781" уже в "N2", "119" в "N1", "360" в "N2", а в "delta" -> "N2-N1".
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что такое `N1` и `N2`?

Comment: Первая позиции и вторая.

Comment: `N1` -- позиция первой буквы слова, а `N2` -- позиция последней буквы слова в в массиве символов текста, так?

Comment: Нет, N1 - позиция первого появление слова в тексте, N2 - второго появление самого слова. Не букв, а самого слова. Если есть третье появление то это N1, четвертое то есть N2 и т.д..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
string value = dataGridView8.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString().ToLower();
string str = richTextBox2.Text.ToLower();
int length = str.Length;
int N1 = 0, N2 = 0, delta = 0, k = 0, i = 0;

// Символьный массив delims должен включать все знаки пунктуации, используемые в тексте
char[] delims = {',', '.', ':', ';', '?', '!', '(', ')', '[', ']',
                 '<', '>', '{', '}', '\'', '\"', '\\', '\n', '\r', '\t'};

// Очистка текста от знаков пунктуации (замена их на пробелы)
for (int j = 0; j <= delims.Length - 1; j++) {
  str = str.Replace(delims[j], ' ');
}

while (true) {
  if (str.Length == length) { 
    i = str.IndexOf(value + " "); // начало текста может не содержать лидирующего пробела
    if (i == -1) break;
  }
  else {
    i = str.IndexOf(" " + value + " "); // далее текст разделен на слова пробелами
    if (i == -1) break;
    else i++;            // уточняем позицию найденного слова
  }

  k++;
  if (k % 2 == 1) {  // k - нечётное
    N1 = i + length - str.Length;                  
  }
  else {  // k - чётное
    N2 = i + length - str.Length;
    if (N2 > N1) {
      delta = N2 - N1;
      dataGridView9.Rows.Add(value, N1.ToString(), N2.ToString(), delta.ToString());
    }
  }
  str = str.Substring(i + value.Length); // усечение строки с "головы"
}

if (k % 2 == 1 && N1 > N2) {  // в случае, когда для N1 нет парного N2, используем N2
  delta = N1 - N2;            // из предыдущей пары с учётом порядка следования в тексте
  dataGridView9.Rows.Add(value, N2.ToString(), N1.ToString(), delta.ToString());
}
```

Для надёжного выделения слов в тексте очистим его от знаков пунктуации, заменив их пробелами. Поиск слова будем выполнять, дополнив образец пробелами слева и справа. Тогда получим следующий улучшенный вариант. Указанную вами проблему он решает. Но в тексте могут встретиться и другие особые случаи. Например, изменяемые формы слов: существительные склоняются, глаголы спрягаются и т.д. Так что, совершенствованию предела нет.:)

Comment: Да, занимаюсь TF-IDF и DE. Есть несколько способов определение частоты ключевых слов по методу дисперсионной оценки. Для этого нужны позиции слов в тексте. Спасибо огромное)

Comment: Оно выводит только две позиции слова (последние), а как вывести все позиции которые встречаются?

Comment: Исправил ошибку, попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: Тоже самое, только две позиции выводит

Comment: Ещё один вариант предлагаю попробовать.

Comment: Выводит все позиции теперь, но когда встречается, что надо вывести все позиции слова "в", то оно выводить позиции всех слов, что начинаются с "в", а не самого "в" позиции

Comment: Эта проблема теперь решена, пробуйте.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает)